# How to update master image from clone image?

Tags: qemu, kvm

In my project I have install openssh-server in clone image(using qemu) i want to update this change to my master image

Comment: can u elaborate ur query

Comment: I have install some software(more than 10 package) in clone image.this software update need to master image how to transfer that changes to clone image to master image .....thanks

Comment: Then why cant use the clone image in place of your master image if the clone image is same as master image

Comment: yes, i have develop a software package,that software package install in various OS.If that software package install in master means i will every time uninstall.so i will use clone image.

Comment: then u can mount your cloned image and also master if required then tranfer data from clone to master

Comment: how to transfer if any comment is there....

Comment: which format of image are u using? vmdk or ext3 or qcow..?

Comment: i have use qcow2 image....